# Returning Integer Value in Obj-C String

Tags: objective-c, xcode, integer

I'm pretty new to Objective-C, switching over from C++, so excuse my stupid question.

I know with `NSLogs` and what not `NSLog(@"%d is the index",i);` is valid syntax. What is the reason that this: `return [UIImage imageNamed:@"cover_%d.jpg", value];` isn't?

I get an error in my IDE telling me that I have too many arguments, i.e. the integer is never being used. How do I get the integer to reflect in a non-log situation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"cover_%d.jpg", value]];`

The string literal syntax doesn't support formats.

Answer (score 2):

The %d (etc.) syntax is a specific convention used by particular functions like NSLog, it's not a general purpose Objective-C operation that you can expect to work with arbitrary method invocations.

Fortunately, another method that supports the %-substitutions is `NSSTRing -stringWithFormat:`. You use that method to create a string using the substitutions, then use that string as desired. For example:

```
NSString *imgName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"cover_%d.jpg", value];
return [UIImage imageNamed:imgName];
```

(you could also combine these two lines into a single expression, eliminating the temporary imgName variable)